# Why do two positive integers equal zero when divided?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, integer

I created a function in my model to determine the dimensions and offset of an image when scaled to fit a certain size with carrierwave:

```
def get_auto_crop_dims(original_width, original_height, cropped_width, cropped_height)
  auto_dims = {:scale_width => 0, :scale_height => 0, :offset_x => 0, :offset_y => 0}

  # IF original image is the SAME orientation as container ie. portrait vs. portrait THEN image largest dimension = 100%
  # IF original image is the DIFFERENT orientation as container ie. portrait vs. landscape THEN image smallest dimension = 100%

  if ((cropped_height >= cropped_width and original_height >= original_width) or (cropped_height >= cropped_width and original_height <= original_width))
    # height 100%
    auto_dims[:scale_height] = cropped_height
    auto_dims[:scale_width] = (auto_dims[:scale_height]/original_height)*original_width
    auto_dims[:offset_y] = 0
    auto_dims[:offset_x] = (auto_dims[:scale_width]-cropped_width)/2
  else 
    # width 100%
    auto_dims[:scale_width] = cropped_width
    auto_dims[:scale_height] = (auto_dims[:scale_width]/original_width)*original_height
    auto_dims[:offset_x] = 0
    auto_dims[:offset_y] = (auto_dims[:scale_height]-cropped_height)/2
  end

  return auto_dims

end
```

It is called with:

```
dims[:title][:width], dims[:title][:height] = `identify -format "%wx%h" #{image.title.file.path}`.split(/x/)
    dims[:title].merge!(get_auto_crop_dims(dims[:original][:width].to_i, dims[:original][:height].to_i, dims[:title][:width].to_i, dims[:title][:height].to_i))

self.dimensions = dims.to_json
```

The returned result, once an image is uploaded, is:

```
> PageImage.last.dimensions
  PageImage Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `page_images`.* FROM `page_images` ORDER BY `page_images`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => "{\"original\":{\"width\":\"1600\",\"height\":\"1200\\n\"},\"title\":{\"width\":\"960\",\"height\":\"384\\n\",\"scale_width\":960,\"scale_height\":0,\"offset_x\":0,\"offset_y\":-192},\"thumb\":{\"width\":\"220\",\"height\":\"130\\n\",\"scale_width\":220,\"scale_height\":0,\"offset_x\":0,\"offset_y\":-65}"
```

---

The problem is:

```
dims[:title][:scale_width] = 0
```

meaning there's some sort of problem with:

```
auto_dims[:scale_height] = (auto_dims[:scale_width]/original_width)*original_height
```

Which I can't make sense of as:

```
:scale_width = 960 & original_width = 1600 & original_height = 1200
```

Why doesn't `dims[:title][:scale_width] = 720`?.

Comment: That's a *ton* of code for what should be a simple problem. What are you getting at here? Can't you trim this down?

Comment: I agree with tadman. A verbose question is difficult to understand. In other words, it is not clear what is asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you divide integers in Ruby, they don't divide into decimals as you expect them too. For example:

- `9 / 4` = 2
- `4 / 9` = 0

What you see in the `4 / 9` is what's happening when you divide scale width by original width, which is a much larger number. To get the decimal you are hoping for, one of the operands must be a floating point number (ex. `4.0 / 9` = 0.444...). So, you could change your code to this:

```
auto_dims[:scale_height] = (auto_dims[:scale_width].to_f/original_width)*original_height
```

The `to_f` call just changes one of the operands to floating point.